# Tangential surface of a smooth algebraic space curve

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, surfaces, complex-geometry, projective-geometry

We know that for a smooth space curve parametrized $$(x_1(t),\; x_2(t),\; x_3(t))$$
the tangential surface (the union of all tangent lines to the curve) is parametrized
$$(x_1(t)+sx_1'(t), \; x_2(t)+sx_2'(t), \; x_3(t)+sx_3'(t))$$
But what about tangential surface of algebraic smooth curves not defined by rational parametrization?
For example $$\begin{cases} XZ+Y^2+W^2 &=0 \\
X^2+XY-Z^2-W^2 &=0 
\end{cases}$$
is a smooth curve in $\mathbb{P}^3_\mathbb{C}$, not contained in every plane, and having genus 1. It's not possible to find a rational parametrization.
So how to compute the tangential surface (find the implicit equation) in these cases?

Comment: Look at this [paper](http://hodge.maths.ed.ac.uk/pdfs/edge/1979a.pdf)